# Install nodejs LTS using Chef in Centos 6.8

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, centos6

I want to install `nodejs` using [rpm.nodesource.com](https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x) on a Centos 6.8 box using Chef. I have a recipe like this

```
    yum_package "gcc-c++" do
      action :install
    end

    yum_package "make" do
      action :install
    end

    cookbook_file "/tmp/node_setup_10.sh" do
      source "node_setup_10.sh"
      owner "root"
      group "root"
      mode "0700"
      action :create
    end

    execute "install nodejs" do
      command "sh /tmp/node_setup_10.sh > /tmp/nodescript.log"
    end

    execute "list packages" do
      command "sh -c \"yum list --showduplicates nodejs > /tmp/yum.log\""
    end

    yum_package "nodejs" do
      action :install
      version 10.15.3-1nodesource
    end
```

It somehow works as it installs `nodejs` but only the second time I run it.

After the first run finishes I see that the `nodejs` 10 package is available but it install 0.10 which is the one that comes with the centos image I'm using.

What is going on here? Do I need to specify any dependency so that the `nodejs` new build package its available during the first install run?

I have added a couple of log files to `tmp` folder and everything seems fine. There is no error message on install script and `yum list` shows versions like

```
    nodejs.x86_64             0.10.48-3.el6                     CentOS-6-Epel-x86_64
    nodejs.x86_64             2:10.15.3-1nodesource             nodesource
    nodejs.x86_64             2:10.16.0-1nodesource             nodesource
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this line: `version node["web_lnx"]["NodejsVersion"]`? When I tested this without chef I see it just installs node v10.15.3

Comment: It is only as a way to define the version I want to use. In my case I have 10.15.3 also. And yes, I first run this without chef and all was good. Ir is only with chef that I need to run it twice to have the LTS version installed.

Comment: Interesting. On my fresh install of centos6.10, `yum install nodejs` fails until I run the `setup_10.x` script. Did you previously add some other nodejs repositories?

Comment: I'm unsure who did the AMI image I'm using, but node 0.10 is available before I run the script.

Comment: How about something like this `yum --disablerepo=CentOS-6-Epel-x86_64 install nodejs`? I believe this will tell it not to look in that repo for the package, thus causing it to find the `nodesource` repo the setup script configures.

Answer (score 0):

i would advise your to look at [nodejs](https://github.com/redguide/nodejs) cookbook to ease your pain